# Epsilon-Delta proof of sum of two continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow a} f(x)+g(x) = f(a)+g(a)$$

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $|f(x)-f(a)|< ε_1$ when $0<|x-a|< \delta_f $ and $|g(x)-g(a)|< ε_2$ $\ $ when $0<|x-a|< _g$

Let  $$ be defined as $\min(_g ,_f)$ and $h(x)$ be defined as $f(x)+g(x)$

$\ |f(x)-f(a)|+|g(x)-g(a)|< ε_1+ε_2$  (1)

$\ |f(x)-f(a) + g(x)-g(a)|< ε_1+ε_2$

$\ |h(x)-h(a)|< ε_1+ε_2$

We can replace $_f$  and  $_g$ by
 $$ to get

$|f(x)-f(a)| < ε_1$ when $0<|x-a|<$ and $\ |g(x)-g(a)|< ε_2$ when $0<|x-a|<$

Since (1) is true when $0<|x-a|<$, we can find a $$ for every value of $ε_1+ε_2$

$\ |h(x)-h(a)|< ε_1+ε_2$ can be rewritten as $\ |h(x)-h(a)|< r_1+r_2$

Any real number can be expressed as the sum of two real numbers so r=$\ r_1+r_2$

Which gives us $\ |h(x)-h(a)|< r$ when $0<|x-a|< $

substituting r=ε we get $\ |h(x)-h(a)|< ε$ when $0<|x-a|< $ for all positive real values of ε.

Is this an acceptable proof?

Comment: A basic element of this proof is the *triangle inequality*.  You have detailed a lot of steps, but it is hard to point to a particular place in the presentation where the triangle inequality is used (although it seems to be related to the first couple of lines in your argument).

Comment: @hardmath Yeah I should've mentioned where I used it. Is the argument in the last lines correct where I have used the property that any real number can be written as the sum of two real numbers? Ignoring the fact that I haven't mentioned the triangle inequality, Would you consider the reasoning of the proof correct?

Comment: I would advise you to use the definition more precisely. I.e. the statement at the beginning and the one after replacing the deltas with one delta seems counterintuitive and as if you've shown what you assumend to be true in the first place. Also, try searching approach0.xyz for this question, surely it has been asked on MSE before.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik From what I understand, you are saying that I assumed what I had to prove in the proof. Can you please elaborate a little and if possible make edits so I can understand what you mean clearly.